# Switch between 2 web pages and pre load them

Tags: php

I want to switch between two web pages and want to preload the page that is comming up next before it is displayed (due to loading time that can not be reduced). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to far? Use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Create both content sections in one page with JavaScript menu to toggle what content is visible.  Initially, make both content sections very simple with a "loading..." message or animation.  Load the actual content for both "pages" with AJAX to replace the loading messages.

You might evaluate why the loading time is so long.  Some content might be broken up to show only what is immediately required for user interaction; for example, load 100 records at a time.  If server processing requires a lot of time, you might consider providing an indication of status.

Comment: Loading time is so long because it is a Tableau server dashboard. There is no way to improve performance unless getting a much faster server.